# How to set the username and password for the admin using database table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, laravel

I have created a website with login form for the administrator. I have the admin table in my database. I added the values in the table but when I try to login, the password is not being accepted. My table is as below

[image]

How can I set username and password for admins using database table?

Comment: How do you want to validate the password, by encryption/decryption or by hash ?

Comment: decryption.....

Comment: Then you can set the datatype of the password as VARCHAR(255) and encrypt the password in your code and store that encrypted password in the field. And, to validate, retrieve the encrypted password string from Db table and decrypt it and match the strings.

Comment: @KishenNagaraju how can i encrypt the pasword

Comment: @KishenNagaraju You would **NEVER** decrypt an already encrypted password nor would you store the password in plain text. You would in almost **ANY** case try to match the two hashes, and if they match that means it's the correct password.

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat Laravel comes with out-of-the-box hashing. If you use the standard authentication scaffolding, you need to set it up to your new table and model "Admin" or else by default it would be the "User" model. You shouldn't create a user through the database, you should instead create it through the application like suggested below by Haider Ali.

Comment: @Classified thanks mate

Comment: @Classified - I am not recommending to store password in plain text. I am recommending to encrypt the password in the code and store the encrypted password in the db table. I suggested this method based on the decryption approach confirmed above by Zubair. If I am not mistaken, this is how encryption/decryption works.

Comment: @KishenNagaraju You would not need to decrypt the password in his case, which also would be a harder task than matching the hashes. Passwords are and should be encrypted for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a hash for the password and I will suggest to use tinker. Just goto your project directory via cmd and type this command

> php artisan tinker

Then Enter below lines to create admin. I assume you have admin model for the admins table!

```
$admin = new App\Admin;
$admin->name= "admin";
$admin->email="admin@admin.com";
$admin->password= Hash::make('password');
$admin->save();
```

Comment: is this laravel inbuilt? i mean will this cause any problem? will i have the root access

Answer (score 0):

```
$admin = new App\Admin;
$admin->name = "admin";
$admin->email ="admin@admin.com";
$admin->password = Hash::make('password');
$admin->save();
```

to hash use:

```
Hash::make('new_password');
```

or

```
bcrypt('new_password');
```